# Laravel attach pivot to table with multiple values

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, pivot-table

#### Background

I'm creating a database revolving around food allergies and I have a many to many relationship between foods and allergies. There is also a pivot value called `severity` which has a numerical number representing the severity of the allergy for that food item.

This link table looks like this;

```
food_id|allergy_id|severity
-------|----------|--------
     1 |        1 |      3
     1 |        4 |      1
     2 |        2 |      1
```

#### The problem

When trying to update the link table with Eloquent (where `$allergy_ids` is an array)

```
$food->allergies()->attach($allergy_ids);
```

How would I go about adding multiple values to this pivot table at once along with the pivot values?

I can add all the `allergy_id`'s for a particular food item in one go using the above line, but how can I also add in the `severity` column at the same time with an array of various severity values? Maybe something like

```
$food->allergies()->attach($allergy_ids, $severity_ids);
```

Edit: There could be between 0-20 allergies for a specific food item, and a severity rating from 0-4 for each allergy, if this helps at all.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can.

From this example in Docs ([4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables), [5.0](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables)):

```
$user->roles()->sync(array(1 => array('expires' => true)));
```

Hardcoded version for the first two rows:

```
$food = Food::find(1);
$food->allergies()->sync([1 => ['severity' => 3], 4 => ['severity' => 1]]);
```

Dynamically, with your arrays $allergy_ids and $severities in a compatible state (size and sort), you shall prepare your sync data before. Something like:

```
$sync_data = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($allergy_ids); $i++))
    $sync_data[$allergy_ids[$i]] = ['severity' => $severities[$i]];

$food->allergies()->sync($sync_data);
```

Comment: Great you solved my problem @Nuno Rafael Figueiredo this worked for me

Comment: @sanu. I'm glad, but shouldn't you upvote my answer?

Comment: Works for `attach` as well. NOTE!!! Using sync will remove all not existing in `$sync_data` and add those not existing in the table. It is the equivalent of `detach()` and then `attach()`. Note exactly equal, but close since exisitng records won't be detached first.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer due to more upvotes, and appears to be more relevant than the old answer from 2 years ago.

Comment: I would just add { } to  $sync_data = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($allergy_ids); $i++) {
    $sync_data[$allergy_ids[$i]] = ['severity' => $severities[$i]];

$food->allergies()->sync($sync_data);}

Answer (score 19):

From version 5.1 of Laravel (Currently in **Laravel 11.x**) onwards it is possible to pass an array as a second argument with all the additional parameters that need to be saved in the intermediate table.
As you can [read in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships)

*When attaching a relationship to a model, you may also pass an array of additional data to be inserted into the intermediate table:*

```
$user->roles()->attach($roleId, ['expires' => $expires]);
```

For convenience, attach and detach also accept arrays of IDs as input:

```
$user->roles()->attach([1 => ['expires' => $expires], 2, 3]);
```

Then you can simply do

```
$food->allergies()->attach([1 => ['severity' => 3], 4 => ['severity' => 1]]);
```

Answer (score 16):

You can't do it like you' like so I suggest a simple loop:

```
foreach ($allergy_ids as $key => $id)
{
  $food->allergies()->attach($id, array_get($severity_ids, $key));
  // should you need a sensible default pass it as a 3rd parameter to the array_get()
}
```

workaround
However if you wanted to attach multiple allergies with single severity level/id then you could do this:

```
$food->allergies()->attach($allergy_ids, array('severity' => $singleSeverityValue));
```

Comment: foreach ($allergy_ids as $key => $id)
    {
    $food->allergies()->attach([$id], ['severity' => array_get($severity_ids, $key)]);
    }

This is the updated version of the code that I used to get it to work. Turns out the `attach` method expects array to be passed to it. Thank you!

Comment: You mean it didn't work for you without casting $id to an array? It shouldn't be a problem as attach method casts it to array anyway.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk That did the trick! `=>`, my problem was that I had a comma instead :-P

Answer (score 1):

So, on Laravel 9, passing the ids in the array worked for me. Likeso,

`$user->roles()->attach([$a->id,$b->id,$c->id]);` and so on.

I guess instead of passing the string. We can pass just the id or else convert the string into array.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest indeed is to attach with the extra data, like so:

```
$retailer->paymentmethods()->attach($paymentmethod, array('currency' => $paymentmethod->currency));
```

change out the values for food allergy severity, but you get the hint... :-)