# Laravel; How to attach multiple ids and values to pivot table with many-to-many relations?

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, pivot

Now I am developing a web application which enable to make a recipe by selecting multiple foods retrieved from mysql and inputting its amount. My user interface is like this;

**Html**

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('store') }}" method="post">
    Your recipe name: <input type="text" name="recipe_name">

      <!-- Generating multiple rows with jquery-->
      '<tr>
        <td>' + add_food + '<input name="food[]" hidden="true" value="'+ add_food +'"></td>
        <td><input name="amount[]" class="amount" type="number"/></td>
      </tr>'

    <input type="submit" value="Make a recipe!">
</form>
```

**Models and relation**

I have already set up two table called `Dish` and `Food` which has many-to-many relation and these tables are intermediated by pivot table called `dish_food`.

**What I want to do**

I want to create new recipe called 'Pizza' which consists from 80g of bread, 20g of cheese and 10g of sausage. So in my UI I select these three foods and input its amounts, then submit these data. Finally I want to insert `dish_id`, `food_id`, `amount` like this;

```
dish_id| food_id|  amount
-------|--------|--------
     1 |      1 |     80 
     1 |      2 |     20
     1 |      3 |     10
```

**Controller I am struggling now**

```
public function store()
{
    // Here comes some validation...

    // Getting data from UI.

        $name     = Input::get('name');
        $foods    = Input::get('foods');  // $foods is storing multiple data.
        $amounts = Input::get('amount'); // $amounts is storing multiple data.

    // Store recipe name into Dish table.
        $dish = Dish::create([
            'name'  => $name
        ]);

    // Here is my problem.
        $food_ids = Food::where('name', '=', $foods)->get(['id']);

        foreach($food_ids as $position => $food_id){

            $dish->foods()->attach($food_id, array_get($amounts, $position));

        return Redirect::route('create-recipe')
                ->with('global', 'You have made one recipe!');
}
```

**Problem**

With the code above, I could insert a new recipe name into `Dish` table like this;

```
dish_id|  name
-------|--------
     1 |  pizza
```

**But** I can't insert multiple data into my pivot table `dish_food`, and I can not get any error message! So I need YOUR help. HOW TO FIX MY CODE?

I already checked related question like this;

[Laravel attach pivot to table with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226802/laravel-attach-pivot-to-table-with-multiple-values)

Comment: Oddly, when I post one food_id, it goes well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are getting just one id in this line

```
 $food_ids = Food::where('name', '=', $foods)->get(['id']);
```

Try to change it to

```
$food_ids = Food::whereIn('name', $foods)->get(['id']);
```