# How to update pivot table in laravel 8?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, relationship

I want to update pivot table in laravel 8 .I'm trynig sync method, but only insert first item of an array.

Here is my code

```
         foreach ($products as $product) {
            $quantity        = $product['quantity'];
            $product_id      = $product['product_id'];
            $food_item_price = FoodItemPrice::where('food_item_id', $product_id)->first();
          
            $order->orderFoodItems()->sync([$product_id => [
                'quantity'           => $quantity,
                'food_item_price_id' => $food_item_price->id,
            ]]);
        }
```

In $products may have many products, but with sync method, it only updates first product. How to update pivot table properly?

Comment: [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations) says that this is how it's supposed to work. I think you need `syncWithoutDetaching` to not dettach previously attached relationships

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30351384/8158202 Check this comment. This contains solution to your problem.

Comment: Problem has solved. I simply changed my code to this                                            
                 $data[ $product_id] = [
                    'quantity'           => $quantity,
                    'food_item_price_id' => $food_item_price->id,
                ];             
                $order->orderFoodItems()->sync($data);