# Add values of an array comming from a form in a pivot table

Tags: arrays, laravel, forms, synchronization, pivot

my database is
a teacher has many classes for a number of hours and a class has mant teachers for a number oh hours.
my pivot table looks like
class_id, teacher_id , nbHours

I don't know how to insert the number of hours in my pivot table when i store a new teacher.

Actually, It creates for my teacher too many classes (all de classes with all the numbers of hours). Of course ! I dont know how to manage.

I tried
my form :
          Classes :  
@foreach($classes as $classe)
id }} '
>
{{$classe->libelle}}

```
                             <label>/ nombre d'heures :  </label> 
                             <input 
                                type="number"  
                                id="Ztext"
                                value="0"
                                class="form-text" 
                                name="nbHeures[]" 
                             
                             >
                         <br>
                          
                    @endforeach`
```

and my controller

```
`         public function store(ProfRequest $profRequest): RedirectResponse
           {
           $prof = Prof::create($profRequest->all());
           $heures=$profRequest->nbHeures ;
           $taille=count($heures) ;
           for($i=0 ; $i<$taille ; $i++){
           $prof->classes()->attach($profRequest->classe_id ,
```

['nbHeures' => $profRequest->nbHeures[$i]]);
}

Comment: Unclear what you want but look into sync and syncWithoutDetaching

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel attach pivot to table with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226802/laravel-attach-pivot-to-table-with-multiple-values)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.